# Issue with an equation using c++

Tags: c++, math, game-physics

Im trying to model the equation of trajectory (for 2d-tank game). The equation im trying to use is:

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+x*tan(60)+-+(9.82+*+x%5E2)+%2F+(2+*+150%5E2+*+cos%5E2(60))](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20%3D%20x*tan(60)%20-%20(9.82%20*%20x%5E2)%20%2F%20(2%20*%20150%5E2%20*%20cos%5E2(60)))

This is an example using 150 as my initial velocity and 60 degrees as the angle. Looking at this graph the root should be x=1984.

In c++ i have:

```
if (shoot) {
    x += elapsed*500;
    y = x*tan(60) - (g * pow(x, 2)) / (2 * pow(150, 2) * pow(cos(60), 2));
}
```

where elapsed is the time elapsed in seconds  since the last frame and g is 9.82. My issue is that the shoot lands at x=1378 and has the highest y value of around 200. I think i modeled the equation correctly so i dont really now what my fault is. For the trajectory i followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EjQkutYOZg

Comment: Trigonometric functions take radians rather then degrees IIRC.

Comment: degrees*(PI/180), assuming you're using `std` functions.

Comment: thanks, are there no functions that takes degrees?

Comment: Yes, one that you write to convert degrees to radians. This is trivial BTW; Google for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work in radians not degrees.

Change the 60 to whatever `60*(PI/180)` equals and the equation will work. Where PI is that circle thing 3.1415...